# Brave-Browser Where is the brave history stored

Tags: 20.04, brave

Where is my browsing history stored in the file system on my local machine?
I use Ubuntu 20.04, and my need is to delete only specific history from my browing history using regex queries.

Is the browsing history of brave stored in a human readable, or a script readable format? or does brave encrypt the browsing history?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20

Comment: https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/ @David

Comment: IIRC they are hidden files in the Brave snap directory and are binary files. If using Nautilus, Navigate to `/Home/snap/brave press `Ctrl+H` to reveal hidden files then navigate from there to Common/.cache/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Cache/